# Why does this code results in compilation error? [C, Global Variables, 2D Array]

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int arr[12][5];


int score[12][5];
int n;

void chk(){
    int score = 0;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
            scanf("%d",&(arr[i][j]));
         }
    }


    for(int i = n-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
           if(i==n-1)
               score[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            else{
               int mx = score[i+1][j];
               if(j>0 && score[i+1][j-1]>mx)
                   mx = score[i+1][j-1];
               else if(j<4 && score[i+1][j+1]>mx)
                   mx = score[i+1][j-1];
               score[i][j] = arr[i][j] + mx;
            }
       }
   }

   int mx_score = score[0][2];
   if(score[0][1]>mx_score){
       mx_score = score[0][1];
   }
   else if(score[0][3]>mx_score){
       mx_score = score[0][3];
   }

   printf("%d",mx_score);
}

int main(){
   int T;
   scanf("%d",&T);
   for(int i = 0;i<T;i++){
      scanf("%d",&n);
      chk(n);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector.
```

The variable that causes the error is `score`.
I don't understand why `arr` works fine but `score` doesn't.
And how would you write this code better?

Indented the properly I think

Comment: One way the code should be improved is by indenting it properly.

Comment: Sorry about this.

Comment: While [edit]s to the question to provide additional information are encouraged, edits which change the question sufficiently to invalidate an already posted answer are not permitted. In fact, the consensus is that any user with [edit privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) should revert such edits. I will do so shortly after posting this comment. Please note that this does not prevent you from completely changing a question prior to any answers being posted. We'd be happy to answer a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int score[12][5];
> void chk() {
> int score = 0;
> ...
> ```

You redeclare `score`; so in the scope of the `chk` function, `score` represents an `int` not an array nor a pointer. Hence the

> *Compilation error: Subscripted value is not an array, pointer or vector*.

Declaring a local variable hides any global variable with the same name. If you need *both* variables within the *same scope*, give them different names.